# How do I create a custom UI component with Visual Studio for Mac / Xcode?

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, visual-studio

I am trying to make a custom `NSTextField` using Visual Studio for Mac and its integration with Xcode.  In trying to work out exactly how to get Xcode to know my `CustomTextField`, I'm having trouble.

So far, when I try to insert the .h and .m stub files to my project navigator, they seem to create ok.  I can see them in the list of files.

But when I save and return to VS, and then go back to the storyboard file, the new files are missing.

So, how is this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

Duh!  I found my own answer to this.  I needed to create a Library Project inside XCode and attach it to my application project.  Then the .h and .m were able to be created in the new library.